# ORA-1691: unable to extend lob segment

Tags: oracle

Estou fazendo uma carga de um banco oracle para outro banco e no momento da transferência dos arquivos de uma tabela de Anexo ocorreu este erro após algum tempo: ORA-1691.

Lendo um pouco vi que tem relação com espaço de armazenamento mas não sei como verificar o tamanho atual nem o que solicitar a equipe de infra. Seria "aumentar o tablespace"? Mas para quantos MB devo pedir esse aumento?

Tem como consultar isso via select no banco sem ser owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para saber o tamanho de uma tablespace é necessário saber o tamanho dos arquivos de dados que constituem esta tablespace.
Para isto podemos utilizar as seguintes querys para verificar o tamanho de um banco de dados.
— Tamanho do banco

```
select sum(bytes) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 tamanho_GB from dba_segments;
```

— ou

```
select sum(bytes) /1073741824  TAMANHO_GB from dba_segments;
```

— Tamanho por Tablespace

```
select tablespace_name, sum(bytes) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 tamanho_GB from dba_segments group by tablespace_name;
```

Comment: Valeu Dante vou fazer um teste aqui e retorno já.

Comment: Preciso de alguma permissão especial para executar este select? Executei tanto na origem quanto no destino mas diz que a tabela dba_segments não existe.

Comment: Só precisa ser o Owner do banco...

Comment: Não sou owner. Vou entrar em contato com o suporte